# Meteor Update Error: Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.14

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, fsevents

When I try to perform Meteor Update (from Meteor 1.4.1 to 1.4.2), I'm getting the following errors:

`node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.14 and node@4.6.1 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)`

`AttributeError: 'MSVSProject' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

Here is my configuration:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Meteor 1.4.1 -> 1.4.2
- NPM 3.3.12
- Node.js 4.5.0

I have read numerous posts on this and I'm unclear about what to do.  Some posts seem to imply that the onus is on me to build on OS X (which would be very difficult given my workflow) or to somehow modify a Shrinkwrap file (not sure exactly how to do this).

Step-by-step instructions to fix this would be very helpful and I'd be eternally grateful (as would other developers).  I'm not being lazy, I've been reading related posts for a couple of hours now and I'm stumped.

Complete log below (thanks in advance for any help you can provide):

```
    => Errors while upgrading packages:

    While loading package momentjs:moment@2.15.2:
    error: Command failed: C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd rebuild --update-binary
    node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.14/fse-v1.0.14-node-v46-win32-ia32.tar.gz
    node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.14 and node@4.6.1 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in 
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 523, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 2003, in GenerateOutput
    sln_projects, project_objects, flat=msvs_version.FlatSolution())
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1762, in _GatherSolutionFolders
    return _DictsToFolders('', root, flat)
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1715, in _DictsToFolders
    for folder, contents in bucket.iteritems():
    AttributeError: 'MSVSProject' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
    gyp ERR! configure error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
    "--module=C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\momentjs_moment\\2.15.2\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-adheq9\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32\\fse.node" "--module_name=fse"
    "--module_path=C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\momentjs_moment\\2.15.2\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-adheq9\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-adheq9\node_modules\fsevents
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.1
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node.exe C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
    --module=C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-adheq9\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32\fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-adheq9\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32' (1)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\momentjs_moment\\2.15.2\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-adheq9\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-adheq9\node_modules\fsevents
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.1
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.29
    node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "rebuild" "--update-binary"
    npm ERR! node v4.6.1
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! fsevents@1.0.14 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the fsevents@1.0.14 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fsevents package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs fsevents
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls fsevents
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-adheq9\npm-debug.log
    node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.14/fse-v1.0.14-node-v46-win32-ia32.tar.gz
    node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.14 and node@4.6.1 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in 
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 523, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 2003, in GenerateOutput
    sln_projects, project_objects, flat=msvs_version.FlatSolution())
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1762, in _GatherSolutionFolders
    return _DictsToFolders('', root, flat)
    File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1715, in _DictsToFolders
    for folder, contents in bucket.iteritems():
    AttributeError: 'MSVSProject' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
    gyp ERR! configure error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
    "--module=C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\momentjs_moment\\2.15.2\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-adheq9\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32\\fse.node" "--module_name=fse"
    "--module_path=C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\momentjs_moment\\2.15.2\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-adheq9\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-adheq9\node_modules\fsevents
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.1
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node.exe C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
    --module=C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-adheq9\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32\fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-adheq9\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32' (1)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\momentjs_moment\\2.15.2\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-adheq9\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-adheq9\node_modules\fsevents
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.1
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.29
    node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "rebuild" "--update-binary"
    npm ERR! node v4.6.1
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! fsevents@1.0.14 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the fsevents@1.0.14 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fsevents package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs fsevents
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls fsevents
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-adheq9\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: You need to update your project by going to your meteor project and running `meteor update`. If you follow the rabbit hole further in this one,you can sort it using `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` which usually solves  a misnaming error.

Comment: @Gandalf, this log is actually being created when I run `meteor update` - I want you to know that I found more information over at Github.

Comment: From tcastelli at GitHub: 

_The problem seems to come from package momentjs:moment@2.15.2 , so reverting to momentjs:moment@2.15.1 should work for now. To do so, go to your .meteor/versions file inside your meteor project and change the 2.15.2 for 2.15.1 and give it a try.

There's an open issue on momentj repo to revise what could have happened with latest version, but staying at 2.15.1 for a while won't kill anyone I guess :)_

Comment: Cool. You could add a link to the issue on github to your answer.

Comment: Gandalf, here is a link to GitHub:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7960#issuecomment-256509433

Answer (score 3):

tcastelli at GitHub writes:

*The problem seems to come from package momentjs:moment@2.15.2 , so reverting to momentjs:moment@2.15.1 should work for now. To do so, go to your .meteor/versions file inside your meteor project and change the 2.15.2 for 2.15.1 and give it a try. There's an open issue on momentj repo to revise what could have happened with latest version, but staying at 2.15.1 for a while won't kill anyone I guess :)*

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7960#issuecomment-256509433